# Php while inside for - What's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, while-loop

This code is to read contents of a text file that contains 100 urls one in each line. The script is to search for a particular word in the urls using file_get_contents.

```
<?php  
$mysearch = file("phpelist.txt");  

for($index = 0; $index <count($mysearch); $index++)  
{  while ($index >=10 && $index <=20 ):

    $mysearch[$index] = str_replace("\n", "", $mysearch[$index]);  
    $data = file_get_contents("$mysearch[$index]");  

    $searchTerm = 'about';  

    if (stripos($data, $searchTerm) !== false) {
        echo "$mysearch[$index]</strong>...FOUND WORD<br><strong>";  
    } 
    else 
    {  
        echo "$mysearch[$index]</strong>...NO SUCH WORD<br><strong>";  
    }  
 endwhile;
} 

?>
```

Comment: `$index` not modified inside `while` once it enters never exit

Comment: Are you sure this code runs? It looks like you have syntax error there... When using `endwhile` you should use `while(...) : `

Comment: and read the other comment as well :)

Comment: Perhaps what you want is an `if` instead of `while`? Anyways, the syntax is wrong as it currently is, like mentioned above - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: Hi, I changed while to if and it shows all the urls. I need lines between 10 and 20.

Answer (score 0):

Your code confused me.  Looking at just the requirements statement, I got ...

```
$searchTerm = 'about';
$file = new SplFileObject('phpelist.txt');
foreach ($file as $n => $url) {
    if ($n < 10) continue;
    if ($n > 20) break;

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    if (stripos($content, $searchTerm) !== false) {
        echo "<strong>$url</strong>...FOUND WORD<br>";
    } else {
        echo "<strong>$url</strong>...NO SUCH WORD<br>";
    }
}
```

CORRECTED: Additional requirements (see comments below).  Which means its no longer much short than OP.  The only thing it adds, I guess, is the use of `SplFileObject`.  I like using `SplFileObject` because it lets you use a file like an array (without loading the entire file into memory) and so can be used in a `foreach` (since `SplFileObject` implements the `Iterator` interface).

Comment: Hi, I need the script to read lines between 10 and 20. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: I'm also just realising now that you are not searching in the URL but the content retrieved from that URL.  Let me fix it ...